# Trying to make pass a value to a data table using tabulator in a Laravel 5.4 framework

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

So I am using a controller to pass a value to a view like so

```
use App\Products;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
    public function index()
{
    $main = Products::all();
    return view('application.minierp', compact('main'));
}
```

When I try to receive the value like this

```
<div id="minierp-table">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var tabledata = {{ $main }}

        //load sample data into the table
        $("#minierp-table").tabulator("setData", tabledata);

    </script>
</div>
```

The Table doesn't even load in at all

I left out a bit of the code that sets up the table but it's not needed for the example because I got it to work by doing something like this

```
var tabledata = <?php include '/home/vagrant/code/minierp/resources/assets/ajax/data.php' ?>
```

The code at that location is simply this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

$dataPull = new AlscoDBsController;
echo $dataPull->data();
```

the function for data() is simply this

```
public function data()
{
    $main = Products::all();
    return $main;
}
```

But I need it to work using the controller so I can pass data into it properly and utilize it using Laravel.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: return your data in json format with this code `return response()->json($main);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var tabledata = {!! $main !!};
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is the only solution that worked for the OP! Wow

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
var tabledata = {{ $main }}
```

to

```
var tabledata = {!! json_encode($main) !!}
```

> explanation - When you are echoing the it just calls the
>   **`__toString`** method to use it you need to make a javascript object or the value that javascript understands

Comment: I actually tried this originally When I load it in and look at the HTML the table isn't present but it says that it tries to load it in the first tabledata is what it's trying to give it in this case the second is what is should be giving it

                    var tabledata = [{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;item&quot;:&quot;000-005&quot;,&quot;um&quot;:&quot;EA&quot;,&quot;package&quot;:1, etc...
                    //var tabledata = [{"id":1,"item":"000-055","um":"EA","package":1,"vendor":467,"class":"","priceclass":"FAB","vendor-item":"000-005","added":"1993

Comment: Check in view source see if the js is broken or not

Comment: This won't work because {{ }} escapes the Json. You need to use {!! !!} so that the Json is not escaped. Also there's no need to json encode as laravel json encodes all models and collections when outputted as strings

Answer (score 0):

Add the value for view into an array

```
return view('application.minierp', ['main'=>json_encode($main)]);
```

Then, in view file, in Javascript use:

```
var tabledata = {!! $main !!};
```

- See this tutorial about passing data to view: http://coursesweb.net/laravel/views#anc_pdv

Comment: I tried this same results. The real problem is that when a Laravel is passing the variable over all of the " (quotation marks) are turned into a &quot; tag

Comment: If you want to not encode html entities, like: `< > "`, use this syntax in your view: `{!! $main !!}`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't change anything else but this and it worked

```
var tabledata = {!! $main !!};
```

before the "" marks in the HTML were being changed to " tags so the by adding the !! fixed this. Second by having two brackets {{}} was adding an un-needed bracket to the dataset and breaking it. by removing one set of brackets, It rendered properly.